# Bug in validation code, Conditions always true

Tags: c++, validation

I seem to have an issue with my CheckBet() method for a Slot Machine I'm making.

Basically, I check the users bet before I spin the Machines wheels.

For some reason CheckBet() is returning true. I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly.

The Problem is, the "SETUP CODE" will ALWAYS run.

SETUP CODE

```
validbet = CheckBet(Player_Bet, Player_Chips);
            if(validbet);
            {

                Player_Chips = DeductChips(Player_Bet, Player_Chips);
                RedrawStatistics(Player_Chips, Winning_Chips, Player_Bet);
                //Winning_Chips = CheckResult(SpinChamber(40, 11, 2), SpinChamber(39, 11, 1), SpinChamber(38, 11, 0), Player_Bet);
            }
```

CHECKBET

```
inline bool CheckBet(int Player_Bet, int Player_Chips)
{
    bool validbet = true;

    if (Player_Bet <= 0)
    {
        Draw_String(26, 17, "You Must Bet at least 20 Chips");
        validbet = false;
    }
    else if (Player_Bet > Player_Chips)
    {
        Draw_String(26, 17, "You don't own that many chips!");
        validbet = false;
    }   
    return validbet;
}
```

Comment: not sure it matters, but you check for `Player_Bet <= 0` but the text says: "Must Bet at least 20 Chips"

Comment: for what input is `CheckBet` returning true?

Comment: I'll change that to 20, but it doesn't change the problem sadly. Thanks though.

Comment: what is "the problem" ? From the code you show I can only see that sometimes it should return `true` and sometimes `false`, so whats wrong about that?

Comment: The code in the if statement (SETUP CODE) always runs. Even if the Player_Bet is outwith the boundaries of "< 19" " > Player_Chips"

Comment: Can you show how you call the function?

Comment: I already have. It's in SETUP CODE.

Comment: Found the issue, semi colon after the if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if(validbet);
```

Your if statement isn't doing anything!

Then this block of code gets executed always - it's not related to the if:

```
{
    Player_Chips = DeductChips(Player_Bet, Player_Chips);
    RedrawStatistics(Player_Chips, Winning_Chips, Player_Bet);
    //Winning_Chips = CheckResult(SpinChamber(40, 11, 2), SpinChamber(39, 11, 1), SpinChamber(38, 11, 0), Player_Bet);
}
```

remove the `;` after the if statement so that the block is the statement that the if applies to:

```
if(validbet)
{
    Player_Chips = DeductChips(Player_Bet, Player_Chips);
    RedrawStatistics(Player_Chips, Winning_Chips, Player_Bet);
    //Winning_Chips = CheckResult(SpinChamber(40, 11, 2), SpinChamber(39, 11, 1), SpinChamber(38, 11, 0), Player_Bet);
}
```

Comment: I can spend inordinate amounts of time looking at my code trying to find things like that.  I wonder if gcc's 'statement has no effect' warning would have found it?